# history.pushState would refetch all resources on manifest.json. Any ways to avoid it?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-history, pushstate, html5-history, manifest.json

When using history.pushState, Chrome (I have not tested other browsers yet, but most of my users are using Chrome) would make requests on all the resources listed on manifest.json, which include a number of icons. I think it is quite unnecessary. Any ways to avoid it?

Thanks!